# Split a String into Two Variables By Separator

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this

```
$string = 'Name of product | 34';
```

I want to break it into two new strings that'll be this:

```
$productName = 'Name of product';
$productPrice = '34';
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this quite simply using [`list()`](http://php.net/list) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
list($productName, $productPrice) = explode(" | ", $string);
```

```
$productName    string(15) "Name of product"
$productPrice   string(2) "34"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$newarray = explode(" | ", $string);
echo $newarray[0]; //Name of product
echo $newarray[1]; //34
```

Comment: what if we don't have idea how long string may be, and how many parts we may have ?

Comment: @Ans - you should count() or sizeof() array and get the number of elements